# What is the 'this' keyword refer to in 'this.model.toJSON'?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, this

Can someone explain to me what the 'this' in "this.model.toJSON()" refers to? I'm reasoning that the 'this' should refer to the object `ContactView`, since that is the object that its located in. But that doesn't seem to be the case. Is 'this.model' connected to the variable Contact?

```
var Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
    photo: "/img/placeholder.png"
  }
});

var ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
   tagName: "article",
   className: "contact-container",
   template: $("#contactTemplate").html(),

   render: function () {
      var tmpl = _.template(this.template);

    this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
   }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript "this" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: I'm flagging this question because it is a specific case of "what does 'this' mean in JavaScript?", which is a good question, but there is already a canonical answer on SO.

Comment: Why isn't it the view? The view has a model, the contact.

Comment: @TomPanning I don't buy the general-purpose answer in the case of a specific framework/etc since `this` binding in JS depends a lot on the context of the JS, how this function is called, etc.

Comment: Okay. So a view automatically receives a model when it's created? You don't have to pass it as a parameter to the view?

Comment: I'm with @DaveNewton here, that question is relevant but the specifics of how `this`, events, a view's `model` option, ... behave in Backbone are probably at the root of the problem so I'm not pulling out the Golden Close Hammer.

Comment: How do you instantiate your `ContactView`? If you want a `model` property, you have to say `new ContactView({ model: something })`, Backbone won't figure it out on its own.

Comment: @DaveNewton If this isn't a general question on "this", then it should be edited to be a specific question about what "this" means in Backbone views

Comment: @TomPanning I'm trying to clarify what the problem really is. Anyone that is familiar with Backbone would recognize this as a Backbone problem more than a JavaScript problem.

Comment: @TomPanning The question already states they're asking about `this` in a specific context.

Comment: @DaveNewton Do you agree that a better form of this question would be "What does 'this' refer to in a Backbone View"? Then it's not a general 'this' question, and also not a "what's going on in my code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 contact = new Contact({name:Mike,location:'Chicago'});
 contactView = new ContactView({model: contact});
 contactView.render();
```

Yes, you're right. 'this' have the current context, in your case it is the current view object. If you're executing your view using above code snippet, this.model.toJSON() return the json object.

Comment: I get it now. Didn't think of that the model is added when the view is instantiated.